# Winnovative Html to PDF footer line

Tags: winnovative

I am using the Winnovative HTML to PDF converter and always getting the footer line even though I have set PdfFooterOptions.DrawFooterLine to false. I am calling a HtmlToPdfArea method to create the content in the footer.

Has anyone ever seen this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably use an old version because the current version supports highly customizable headers and footers. Please [check this HTML to PDF demo with complete C# code](http://www.winnovative-software.com/htmltopdfdemo/HtmlInHeaderAndFooter.aspx) to see how to add or not a line in header or footer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below and its working fine for me hope this help

```
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.AddTextArea(new TextArea(250, 10, 50, "Page &p; of &P;", new Font(new FontFamily("Arial"), 8)));
        pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.DrawFooterLine = false;
```